# how to display data obtained from dao in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

in jsp

```
<table width="100%" id='table1'  border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr class="tab-highlighted-2">
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="10%">
          <div align="left">Project ID</div>
        </td>
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="10%">
          <div align="left">Project Name</div>
        </td>
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="20%">
          <div align="left">Cost Center</div>
        </td>
        <td class="tab-highlighted-2" width="20%">
          <div align="left">Manager</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr class="bg-row1">
  <c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="resultList"> 
        <td class="td-highlighted-2">
         <div align="left"><a href="UpdateProject.html">${resultList.Projid}</a></div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-highlighted-2">
          <div align="left">${resultList.Projname}</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-highlighted-2">
          <div align="left">${resultList.Cost}</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-highlighted-2">
          <div align="left">${resultList.Manager}</div>
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    </table>
```

in dao

```
public final class SearchProjDAO   
{ 
    private static InitialContext context;  
    String CLASS_NAME="DBConnectionFactory";  

    public ArrayList  submitProjectDetails(SearchProjVO searchprojVO)   
    {  
        ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
        String methodname="createConnection";
        Connection conn  = null;
        PreparedStatement psmt;
        try {
            System.out.println("in DAO");
            System.out.println("searchprojVO id=="+searchprojVO.getProjid());

            conn = DBConnection.getJNDIConnection();
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String query="select * from CR_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS";if(searchprojVO.getProjid()!=null || searchprojVO.getProjname()!=null || searchprojVO.getManager()!=null)
            query=query+" where ";
        if(searchprojVO.getProjid()!=null)
            query=query+" PROJ_ID="+searchprojVO.getProjid();
        if(searchprojVO.getProjname()!=null)
            query=query+"PROJ_NAME="+searchprojVO.getProjname();
        if(searchprojVO.getCost()!=null);
            query=query+"PROJ_COST="+searchprojVO.getCost();
        if(searchprojVO.getManager()!=null)
            query=query+"PROJ_MANAGER="+searchprojVO.getManager();

            psmt= conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs=psmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                SearchProjVO projVO = new SearchProjVO();
                projVO.setProjid(rs.getString("PROJ_ID"));
                projVO.setManager(rs.getString("PROJ_NAME"));
                projVO.setProjname(rs.getString("PROJ_COST"));
                projVO.setManager(rs.getString("PROJ_MANAGER"));
             ar.add(projVO);
                                }

            System.out.println("conn==="+conn); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } 

        return ar;
    }

}
```

Comment: You will get more/better answers if you tell us what's working or not working with the code you've pasted. People aren't usually keen on the old slap-down-some-code-and-tell-me-whats-wrong-with-it questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spot several mistakes:

Here,

```
<c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="resultList">
```

You're overriding the list value with the value of the list item everytime. Don't do that. Give the `var` an unique variable name. The entity name is the most straightforward choice.

```
<c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="project">
```

*Note that I'd personally also rename the nothing-saying `resultList` to a more self-explaining `projects`.*

---

And here,

```
<tr class="bg-row1">
    <c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="project">
```

the flow is wrong. You should print a new row **inside** each loop. Swap them.

```
<c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="project"> 
    <tr class="bg-row1">
```

---

And here,

```
${resultList.Projid}
${resultList.Projname}
${resultList.Cost}
${resultList.Manager}
```

the property names must start with lowercase (and fix the item name to be the same as in `var`).

```
${project.projid}
${project.projname}
${project.cost}
${project.manager}
```

*Note that I'd personally also get rid of `proj` prefix in some property names.*

---

And finally you're forgotten a closing `</c:forEach>`.

```
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, your JDBC code is sensitive to SQL injection attacks and is leaking resources. Fix it as well.

Comment: Then `${resultList}` is not been set by servlet for the JSP.