# unable to display data obtained from dao in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, dao

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display data obtained from dao in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216386/how-to-display-data-obtained-from-dao-in-jsp)

hi i able to retrieve the data and print it on the console but i am unable to print the data in jsp below is the code in dao

```
while(rs.next())  
            {  
                 System.out.println(rs.getString(1) +" " + rs.getString(2)+ " "+rs.getString(3) +" " + rs.getString(4)+"<br>");  

                 SearchProjVO projVO = new SearchProjVO();
                 projVO.setProjid(rs.getString(1));
                projVO.setProjname(rs.getString(2));
                projVO.setCost(rs.getString(3));
                projVO.setManager(rs.getString(4));
                ar.add(projVO);
             }
```

in jsp i am calling those variables in the following format is this correct

```
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
     <div align="left"><a href="UpdateProject.html">${resultList.projId}</a></div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
      <div align="left">${resultList.projName}</div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
      <div align="left">${resultList.cost}</div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
      <div align="left">${resultList.manager}</div>
    </td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: how do you pass the values from the dao to the jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are iterating through a result list.  Assuming you had a list of SearchProjVO objects in a List that was accessible from your page then something like this would work:

```
<c:forEach var="result" items="${resultList}">
    <tr>
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
     <div align="left"><a href="UpdateProject.html">${result.projId}</a></div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
      <div align="left">${result.projname}</div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
      <div align="left">${result.cost}</div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-highlighted-2">
      <div align="left">${result.manager}</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```